# Having a footnote simultaneously on the reference page and also at the end of the document

Tags: footnotes, endnotes

I am having a problem with footnotes. I know there are multiple packages that allow me to create an endnote, but what if I wanted a note, that is simultaneously a footnote and an endnote?

It would appear on the reference page and also at the end of the document.

I looked through the docs of pagenote and endnote and I cannot find anything like it.

Comment: You could create a command which calls both \footnote and \endnote.  You can even use `\let\oldfootnote=\foonote` and redefine \footnote to use \oldfootnote and \endnote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested in the comments, I created a new command.

This is the result I ended up with.

```
\newcommand{\fn}[1]{\stepcounter{footnote}\footnotetext{#1}\endnote{#1}}
\let\footnote=\fn
```

Works perfect!

Answer (score 0):

I am facing issues trying to replicated what you have done.
I have this at the beginning of my document :

```
\usepackage{endnotes}
\usepackage{pagenote}
\renewcommand*{\notedivision}{\chapter*{\notesname}}
\newcommand{\fn}[1]{\stepcounter{footnote}\footnotetext{#1}\endnote{#1}}
\let\footnote=\fn
\makepagenote
```

and where I want the notes to be at the end of the document as well i have written

```
\printnotes
```

But the notes are only visible at the end of the pages. Do you have any idea.

Thank you

Comment: Ask a new question, with reference to this one if appropriate.  Questions posted as answers can't receive proper answers.

Comment: I found the problem, i had to use enotez and pagenotes and not endnotes